# rails server command not starting server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to Rails and am trying to run an application on Windows 8. Whenever I try to start the server using "rails server", it gives me this:

```
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]
Options:
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]     # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
```

etc, I think you get the picture. I have gotten the server running several times before, and I assure that I am in the application directory. Could somebody please provide another explanation as to why this would happen? If you need more information, feel free to ask.

Comment: Are you on the rails app project directory?

Comment: I was. Turns out I simply needed to run "rake rails:update:bin". My server is up and running now. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Checked the value of PATH (echo %PATH%) if Ruby was not in there then add it manually:

> set PATH=C:\Ruby200-x64\bin;%PATH%

I've installed RubyInstaller for Windows (the "Ruby 2.0.0-p247 (x64)" version)
then config the path for your version.